# Metric with one index up and one index down, what does that mean?

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

In one paper, a metric $h_{ab}$ is defined as $g_{ab} - N_a N_b$. The inverse of this metric would be h^{ab}.

But in another line they define an object like $$K_{ab} = h_a^c \nabla_c N_b.$$ What is $h_a^c$? Another way of writing the inverse?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Notations may be introduced in the paper, or are conventions defined for the field. Could you provide more context?

Comment: Hi! Absolutely. In this case, unfortunately, it is not defined. The equation is 2.4 in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0003173.pdf

But I believe it could be like this: h is diagonal so $h_a^c = Tr(h) \delta_a^c$.

Comment: Hi! Does the second paragraph of the introduction provide more clarification? Especially reference #6? That is the first place where I see superscript indices. Also, footnote #1 seems to be helpful.

Comment: If I understand correctly $g_{ab}$ defines the metric of the whole space (in which brane lives), but $h_{ab}$ defines the metric only on brane (the space of lower dimension - $g_{ab}$ minus normal to the brane). If this is the case all indices $a,b$ are related to the whole space (which metric is defined by $g_{ab}$) and, therefore, $h_a^c = g^{bc}h_{ab}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thanks. This actually makes more sense than to interpret it as a trace. I will try to verify one of their equations using your definition and see if it is right, but so far it looks promising.